# BottomNavigationView is not hiding when scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am developing an android app, wherein following layout has been defined to display top navigationview, drawer and bottomnavigation view. However, I am not able to  hide my bottomnavigationview when items in recyclerview are scrolled.

From the available help I have placed `app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"` in the BottomNavigationView, but it appears than since `BottomNavigationView` is in the `ConstraintLayout`, it is not working as expected.

I have also tried to use CoordinatorLayout in place of ConstraintLayout as well, but it is not working and when I am doing this my app hangs.

I have also tried to use CoordinatorLayout nested inside the ConstraintLayout, but here also my app hangs.

Any help is appreciated.
Code for content_dashboard.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_dashboard">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The content of app_bar_dashboard.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mobiapp.hospmgmt.DashboardActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have inserted following custom code to hide BottomNavigationView, but app hangs. Any suggestions.

```
package com.mobiapp.hospmgmt;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class BottomNavigationBehaviour extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<BottomNavigationView> {

    public BottomNavigationBehaviour() {
        super();
    }

    public BottomNavigationBehaviour(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, BottomNavigationView child, View dependency) {
        boolean dependsOn = dependency instanceof FrameLayout;
        return dependsOn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, BottomNavigationView child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int nestedScrollAxes, int type)
    {
        return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull BottomNavigationView child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed,
                               @ViewCompat.NestedScrollType int type)
    {
        if (dyConsumed > 0) {
            hideBottomNavigationView(child);
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0) {
            showBottomNavigationView(child);
        }
    }


    private void hideBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(view.getHeight());
    }

    private void showBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationView view) {
        view.animate().translationY(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you have to place `BottomNavigationView` as a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout` layout. Modify your layout something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Take `ConstraintLayout` as a root in your `@layout/content_dashboard` and place `RecyclerView` and other views over there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_dashboard">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />
        ....
        ....
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it up** by removing `content_dashboard.xml` and putting all the content in a coordinator layout also replaced the `hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior` with custom behavior

Comment: Let me try the changes suggested

Comment: Please see the code changes above. App hangs, it is not working, any suggestions. Error I get is FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mobiapp.hospmgmt, PID: 14429
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobiapp.hospmgmt/com.mobiapp.hospmgmt.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: If I remove CoordinatorLayout from the merged .xml file, system hangs. any further suggestions.

Comment: you have to remove belove parameter from BottomNavigationView. to solve Fatel Exception.

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by moving BottomNavigationView out of ConstraintLayout after merging above two .xml files.
Thanks for support @Vishrut Mavani